# Java Regex: Split based on non-word characters except for apostrophe

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split and include based on spaces and non-word characters, except for apostrophes.

I've been able to make it split and include based on spaces and non-word characters, but I can't seem to figure out how to exclude apostrophes from the non-word characters.

This is my current Regex...

```
str.split("\\s|(?=\\W)");
```

...which when run on this code sample:

```
program p;
begin
    write('x');
end.
```

...produces this result:

```
program
p
;
begin

write
(
'x   <!-- This is the problem.
'
)
;
end
.
```

Which is almost correct, but my goal is to skip the apostrophes so that this is the result:

```
program
p
;
begin

write
(
'x'   <!-- This is the wanted result.
)
;
end
.
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested I've tried:

```
str.split("\\s|(?=\\W)(?<=\\W)");
```

Which almost works, but does not split all of the special characters correctly:

```
program
p;
begin
write(
'x'
)
;
end.
```

Comment: Is this working for you: `([^\\w']+)`

Comment: Does Java [support character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html)? Could be helpful for your case if it does.

Comment: @Toto Hmm that got the apostrophes working, but it didn't include the other special characters: program mini begin write 'x' end

Comment: *I can't seem to figure out how to exclude apostrophes from the non-word characters.* Try `[\w&&[^']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on this.

```
\s|('[^']*')|(?=\W)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mL7eL6/1

Comment: This works great in the Regex101, but I'm not sure how I can add the '\n$1' substitution in Java for it to appear correctly.

Comment: @DarkKnight when split in python...the captured groups appear automatically....not sure in java

Comment: @DarkKnight did u give it a try.just split by it

Comment: I'm not sure how to substitute the captured groups in Java - it does not look like it's an option for the 'split' method.

Comment: @DarkKnight you can use this dirty fix `\s+|(?=[^\w'])|(?='[^']*')`...See demo.https://regex101.com/r/mL7eL6/2

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried...

```
[^\w']
```

This will match any character that is neither a word character nor an apostrophe. May be simple enough to work depending on your inputs.

If you run a replace operation using `[^\w']` as your regex and `\n\1\n` as your replacement string, it should get you close to where you'd like to be.

Comment: This is saying match everything that is *not* a word character *and not* an apostrophe... There is a difference between `[^\w]` and `[^\w']`. Please reconsider your downvote. [Reference this](https://regex101.com/r/yX3kG2/1) versus [this](https://regex101.com/r/yT7mH7/1).

Answer (score 0):

Treat the apostrophe separately and requiring a preceding non-word:

```
str.split("\\s+|(?=[^\\w'])|(?<=\\W)(?=')");
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/zfPqJZ7YJC).

Comment: Hmm - this splits some of the special chars but not all of them: program
mini; begin write( 'x' ) ; end.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative it's possible to scan string for 
\b[\w']+\b